# Sidebar not visible after changing to new domain

Tags: sidebar, domain, migration

I made a change of my existing domain to new domain.

I took the backup of the database from old site and imported it into new database
Used the search and replace widget to replace the old url with new url

But i cant seem to see the sidebar widgets. I can see them on the admin panel but they are not visible on site.

Any pointers on what could be the cause.
I changed the theme to twentyten and the sidebar is visible

Answer (score 0):

Don't replace old url to new url in database file.
wp-login.php can be used to (re-)set the URIs. Find this line:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

and insert the following lines below:

Do comment/remove these lines. (once the database is updated)

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/' );
update_option('home', 'http://your.domain.name/' );
```

for more information http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress